# How to subscribe to click events so exceptions don't unsubscribe?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm using [RxJava for Android (RxAndroid)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) and I subscribe to click events of a view, and do something on them as follows:

```
subscription = ViewObservable.clicks(view, false)
    .map(...)
    .subscribe(subscriberA);
```

The problem is whenever there is an exception, `subscriberA` automatically unsubscribes, leading to the next click not triggering anything.

How to handle exceptions so to intercept all the click events regardless of exceptions being thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`retry`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#retry) method:

```
subscription = ViewObservable.clicks(view, false)
    .map(...)
    .retry()
    .subscribe(subscriberA)
```

However, you will not receive any exception in `onError`.
To handle exceptions with retry (resubscribe) logic use [`retryWhen`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#retrywhen):

```
subscription = ViewObservable.clicks(view, false)
    .map(...)
    .retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Notification<?>>, Observable<?>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(Notification errorNotification) {
            Throwable throwable = errorNotification.getThrowable();
            if (errorNotification.isOnError() && handleError(throwable)) {
                // return the same observable to resubscribe
                return Observable.just(errorNotification);
            }
            // return unhandled error to handle it in onError and unsubscribe
            return Observable.error(throwable);
        }

        private boolean handleError(Throwable throwable) {
            // handle your errors
            // return true if error handled to retry, false otherwise
            return true;
        }
    }
    .subscribe(subscriberA)
```

Comment: It works! This is the answer I need. However, I think the signature of `call` is wrong or outdated, coz Func1 is like this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/functions/Func1.java