# How to ignore error and continue infinite stream?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I would like to know how to ignore exceptions and continue infinite stream (in my case stream of locations)?

I'm fetching current user position (using [Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation)) and then sending them to my API (using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)).

In my case, when exception occurs during network call (e.g. timeout) `onError` method is invoked and stream stops itself. How to avoid it?

Activity:

```
private RestService mRestService;
private Subscription mSubscription;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(100);
...
private void start() {
    mRestService = ...;
    ReactiveLocationProvider reactiveLocationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(this);
    mSubscription = reactiveLocationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(mLocationRequest)
            .buffer(50)
            .flatMap(locations -> mRestService.postLocations(locations)) // can throw exception
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
}
```

RestService:

```
public interface RestService {
    @POST("/.../")
    Observable<Response> postLocations(@Body List<Location> locations);
}
```

Comment: see the similar answer with click events exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154236/how-to-subscribe-to-click-events-so-exceptions-dont-unsubscribe/26229584#26229584

Comment: lol overly complicated setup of the question. You could have reduced this one to a few lines; ignoring project-specific semantics.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`mRestService.postLocations(locations)` emit one item, then complete. 
If an error occur, then it emit the error, which complete the stream.

As you call this method in a `flatMap`, the error continue to your "main" stream, and then your stream stops.

What you can do is to transform your error into another item (as described here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28971140/476690 ), but not on your main stream (as I presume you already tried) but on the `mRestService.postLocations(locations)`.

This way, this call will emit an error, that will be transformed to an item/another observable and then complete. (without calling `onError`).

On a consumer view, `mRestService.postLocations(locations)` will emit one item, then complete, like if everything succeed.

```
mSubscription = reactiveLocationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(mLocationRequest)
        .buffer(50)
        .flatMap(locations -> mRestService.postLocations(locations).onErrorReturn((e) -> Collections.emptyList()) // can't throw exception
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not ignore, but emit empty list. it would be nice do not emit on error

Comment: What do you mean by `// can throw exception`? Does it mean even inside the `onErrorReturn` we might have an exception again?!

Comment: I think it's a mistake and it would be instead : "can't throw exception" (so I just edit the comment.) Nice catch!

Answer (score 78):

You may want to use one of the [error handling operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators).

- `onErrorResumeNext( )` — instructs an Observable to emit a sequence of items if it encounters an error
- `onErrorReturn( )` — instructs an Observable to emit a particular item when it encounters an error
- `onExceptionResumeNext( )` — instructs an Observable to continue emitting items after it encounters an exception (but not another variety of throwable)
- `retry( )` — if a source Observable emits an error, resubscribe to it in the hopes that it will complete without error
- `retryWhen( )` — if a source Observable emits an error, pass that error to another Observable to determine whether to resubscribe to the source

Especialy `retry` and `onExceptionResumeNext` look promising in your case.

Comment: When I add `onExceptionResumeNext(Observable.empty())` after the `flatMap(locations -> mRestService.postLocations(locations))` `onCompleted` is invoked and stream ends.

Comment: Don't add it after the `flatMap`, but inside the `flatMap`.

Comment: Thanks!
onErrorResumeNext( ) - very usefull construction for fallbacks.

Answer (score 20):

If you just want to ignore the error inside the `flatMap` **without returning an element** do this:

```
flatMap(item -> 
    restService.getSomething(item).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
);
```

Comment: This would actually complete the stream. wouldn't it?

Answer (score 7):

Just pasting the link info from @MikeN's answer incase it gets lost:

```
import rx.Observable.Operator;
import rx.functions.Action1;

public final class OperatorSuppressError<T> implements Operator<T, T> {
    final Action1<Throwable> onError;

    public OperatorSuppressError(Action1<Throwable> onError) {
        this.onError = onError;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> t1) {
        return new Subscriber<T>(t1) {

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                t1.onNext(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                onError.call(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                t1.onCompleted();
            }

        };
    }
}
```

> and use it close to the observable source because other operators may
>   eagerly unsubscribe before that.

```
Observerable.create(connectToUnboundedStream()).lift(new OperatorSuppressError(log()).doOnNext(someStuff()).subscribe();
```

> Note, however, that this suppresses the error delivery from the
>   source. If any onNext in the chain after it throws an exception, it is
>   still likely the source will be unsubscribed.

Comment: This works but after an error is suppressed my source observable seems to stop working. Is there a way to restart it?

Comment: @Matthias so this doesn't fix the problem? (Same as with `onErrorResumeNext` - it completes the observable)?

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be a bit late, but if anyone stumbles upon this, instead of reinventing a wheel can use the ready to use Relay lib by Jacke Wharton

https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay

there is good documentation but in essence, Relay is A Subject except without the ability to call onComplete or onError.

and the options are:

**BehaviorRelay**

```
Relay that emits the most recent item it has observed and all subsequent observed items to each subscribed Observer.
```

```
    // observer will receive all events.
    BehaviorRelay<Object> relay = BehaviorRelay.createDefault("default");
    relay.subscribe(observer);
    relay.accept("one");
    relay.accept("two");
    relay.accept("three");

    // observer will receive the "one", "two" and "three" events, but not "zero"
    BehaviorRelay<Object> relay = BehaviorRelay.createDefault("default");
    relay.accept("zero");
    relay.accept("one");
    relay.subscribe(observer);
    relay.accept("two");
    relay.accept("three");
```

**PublishRelay**
Relay that, once an Observer has subscribed, emits all subsequently observed items to the subscriber.

```
    PublishRelay<Object> relay = PublishRelay.create();
    // observer1 will receive all events
    relay.subscribe(observer1);
    relay.accept("one");
    relay.accept("two");
    // observer2 will only receive "three"
    relay.subscribe(observer2);
    relay.accept("three");
```

**ReplayRelay**
Relay that buffers all items it observes and replays them to any Observer that subscribes.

```
    ReplayRelay<Object> relay = ReplayRelay.create();
    relay.accept("one");
    relay.accept("two");
    relay.accept("three");
    // both of the following will get the events from above
    relay.subscribe(observer1);
    relay.subscribe(observer2);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Repay is very handy for an event bus type of broadcasting

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the rest service in a Observable.defer call. That way for every call you'll get a chance to use its own 'onErrorResumeNext' and the errors won't cause your main stream to complete.

```
reactiveLocationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(mLocationRequest)
  .buffer(50)
  .flatMap(locations ->
    Observable.defer(() -> mRestService.postLocations(locations))
      .onErrorResumeNext(<SOME_DEFAULT_TO_REACT_TO>)
  )
........
```

That solution is originally from this thread -> [RxJava Observable and Subscriber for skipping exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390878/rxjava-observable-and-subscriber-for-skipping-exception), but I think it will work in your case too.

Answer (score 1):

Add my solution for this problem:

```
privider
    .compose(ignoreErrorsTransformer)
    .subscribe()

private final Observable.Transformer<ResultType, ResultType> ignoreErrorsTransformer =
        new Observable.Transformer<ResultType, ResultType>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<ResultType> call(Observable<ResultType> resultTypeObservable) {
                return resultTypeObservable
                        .materialize()
                        .filter(new Func1<Notification<ResultType>, Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public Boolean call(Notification<ResultType> resultTypeNotification) {
                                return !resultTypeNotification.isOnError();
                            }
                        })
                        .dematerialize();

            }
        };
```

Comment: What does the materialize operator?

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of the solution (@MikeN) to enable finite streams to complete:

```
import rx.Observable.Operator;
import rx.functions.Action1;

public final class OperatorSuppressError<T> implements Operator<T, T> {
    final Action1<Throwable> onError;

    public OperatorSuppressError(Action1<Throwable> onError) {
        this.onError = onError;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> t1) {
        return new Subscriber<T>(t1) {

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                t1.onNext(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                onError.call(e);
                //this will allow finite streams to complete
                t1.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                t1.onCompleted();
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my kotlin extension function for ignoring errors

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.ignoreErrors(errorHandler: (Throwable) -> Unit) =
    retryWhen { errors ->
        errors
            .doOnNext { errorHandler(it) }
            .map { 0 }
    }
```

This utilizes `retryWhen` to indefinately re-subscribe to the upstream while still allowing you a method of handling the error in a non terminal way.

This feels dangerous

Answer (score 0):

With Rxjava2, we could call the overloaded flatmap with delayErrors parameter:
[flatmap javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-boolean-)

When passing it as true:

> exceptions from the current Flowable and all inner Publishers are delayed until all of them terminate if false, the first one signaling an exception will terminate the whole sequence immediately

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip error using onErrorComplete() method

```
mSubscription = reactiveLocationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(mLocationRequest)
    .buffer(50)
    .flatMapMaybe(locations -> Maybe.just(mRestService.postLocations(locations).onErrorComplete()) // skip item
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();
```