# RxJava2 materialize() doesn't emit next item after an error

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I've been trying to convert my onErrors into notifications in order to keep the stream emitting items. As far as I understood the materialize() operator does just that. So basically:

> materialize() / dematerialize() are available to turn terminal events
>   into Notification

So I made a test for this based on this question ([How to continue streaming items after error in RxJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380757/how-to-continue-streaming-items-after-error-in-rxjava)). I tried the following:

```
 @Test
public void materializeTest() {
    final Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.fromArray("1", "2", "3")
            .flatMap(x -> {
                if (x.equals("2")) {
                    return Observable.error(new NullPointerException());
                }

                return Observable.just(x);
            })
            .materialize()
            .map(n -> n.getValue());

    final TestObserver<String> testObs = stringObservable.test();
    Java6Assertions.assertThat(testObs.values().size()).isEqualTo(2);

    testObs.assertValueAt(0, "1");
    testObs.assertValueAt(1, "3");
}
```

The result is that no more items are emitted after "2" gives the error. I've also tried to warp on my own Notification object (`MyNotification<T>`) and do something like:

```
stringObs
  .map(string -> MyNotification.success(string)
  .onErrorReturn(error -> MyNotification.error())
```

But the end result is always the same: after "2" no more items are emitted. I'm 100% doing something wrong but can't really understand what is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `flatMap`, if one of the inner `Observable`s fails, the sequence is terminated an no further items are transformed from the upstream. That happens **before** `materialize()` even gets involved.

So instead of trying to materialize the merged flow, materialize the inner sources individually:

```
Observable.fromArray("1", "2", "3")
        .flatMap(x -> {
            if (x.equals("2")) {
                return Observable.<String>error(new NullPointerException())
                                 .materialize();
            }

            return Observable.just(x)
                             .materialize();
        })
        .filter(n -> n.isOnNext())
        .map(n -> n.getValue());
```

Comment: I've tried this but it stills fails the test. I was able to pass the test by making a map and onErrorReturn operations to "MyNotification" happening inside the flatmap (basically, what you suggested but without materialize()) I can post that working solution.

Comment: Ah nice! :D Thank you so much. I understand the issue :)