# Making chain of different network calls using Rx2 and Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have this sequential network calls function

```
 private fun fetchData() {
    disposables.add(primaryMenuFetcher.getMenu()
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .flatMap { menuItems ->
                primaryMenu = menuItems
                onView {
                    setPrimaryMenuList(primaryMenu)
                }

                return@flatMap service.getPromotions()
            }
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .subscribe({ fetchedLeagues ->
                featuredLeagues = fetchedLeagues
                onView {
                    showPopularLeagues()
                    setPopularLeaguesList(featuredLeagues)
                    hideProgressBar()
                }
            }, {
                onView {
                    showError()
                    hideProgressBar()
                }
            }))
}
```

Everything is working fine as long as `primaryMenuFetcher.getMenu()` dont have any errors. I want to achieve that if it has error it would be basicaly skiped and `service.getPromotions()` would be called instead of braking whole chain

I dont know how I managed to not figure it out by my self. I just needed to use `.onErrorResumeNext`

Working solution is

```
 private fun fetchData() {
    disposables.add(primaryMenuFetcher.getMenu()
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .flatMap { menuItems ->
                primaryMenu = menuItems
                onView {
                    setPrimaryMenuList(primaryMenu)
                }

                return@flatMap service.getPromotions()
            }
            .onErrorResumeNext { return@onErrorResumeNext service.getPromotions() }
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .subscribe({ fetchedLeagues ->
                featuredLeagues = fetchedLeagues
                onView {
                    showPopularLeagues()
                    setPopularLeaguesList(featuredLeagues)
                    hideProgressBar()
                }
            }, {
                onView {
                    showError()
                    hideProgressBar()
                }
            }))
}
```

Comment: You can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969995/how-to-ignore-error-and-continue-infinite-stream

Comment: Have you checked [onErrorResumeNext](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorresumenext)?

Comment: Solution is in updated question