# Ensure an RxWorker never fails

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-workmanager

I'm implementing my first `WorkManager` for daily sync with the server which could return an HTTP error hence make the `createWork()` flow to fail and to call `onError()` so a `Result.failure()` is "thrown" in the flow's subscription.

I would like to make sure `Result.failure()` is never called and always call `Result.retry()`.

Here is my `RxWorker`

```
class DailySyncWorker (appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): RxWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    private val disposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    private val httpManager = AppFactory.httpManager()
    private val dbManager = AppFactory.dbManager()
    private val prefsManager = AppFactory.sharedManager(appContext)

    companion object {
        const val WORKER_NAME = "com.blabla.blah.DAILY_SYNC_WORKER"
    }

    override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        Timber.e("Worker - Executing ${System.currentTimeMillis() - prefsManager.lastMillis}")
        prefsManager.lastMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

        return dbManager.alarmDAO.getNewAlarms(prefsManager.lastSyncedAlarm)
            .flatMap { alarms -> syncWithServer(alarms)
                .doOnSuccess {
                    if(alarms.size != 0)
                        prefsManager.lastSyncedAlarm = alarms[0].date // The query is in descending order, the first record is the last recorded alarm
                }
            }
    }

    private fun syncWithServer(alarms: MutableList<Alarm>): Single<Result> {
        val syncRequestModel = SyncRequestModel(alarms)

        return if(alarms.size != 0)
            httpManager.service().create(SyncService::class.java).sync(syncRequestModel)
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMap { result ->
                        if(result == "OK") { // TODO - the service has not been created yet
                            Timber.e("Worker - success")
                            Single.just(Result.success())
                        } else {
                            Timber.e("Worker - failure")
                            Single.just(Result.retry())
                        }
                    }
        else {
            Timber.e("Worker - no sync is necessary")
            Single.just(Result.success())
        }
    }
}
```

I tried calling `Result.retry()` in many different `onError()` of the flow but it seems that `Result.failure()` is being called in the `onError()` of the subscription which I can't override.

So how can I make sure my worker never fails?

Comment: use onErrorXXX, maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969995/how-to-ignore-error-and-continue-infinite-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `syncWithServer()` function, you only check result in `flatMap` part. However, there might be cases that error might happen before reaching `flatMap` part which means `Result.retry()` might never be returned. Also, you do not need to specify specific thread as workers run on background thread by default. Here is your worker with changes I mentioned above:

```
class DailySyncWorker (appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): RxWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    private val disposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    private val httpManager = AppFactory.httpManager()
    private val dbManager = AppFactory.dbManager()
    private val prefsManager = AppFactory.sharedManager(appContext)

    companion object {
        const val WORKER_NAME = "com.blabla.blah.DAILY_SYNC_WORKER"
    }

    override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        Timber.e("Worker - Executing ${System.currentTimeMillis() - prefsManager.lastMillis}")
        prefsManager.lastMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

        return dbManager.alarmDAO.getNewAlarms(prefsManager.lastSyncedAlarm)
            .flatMap { alarms -> syncWithServer(alarms)
                .doOnSuccess {
                    if(alarms.size != 0)
                        prefsManager.lastSyncedAlarm = alarms[0].date // The query is in descending order, the first record is the last recorded alarm
                }
            }
            .onErrorReturnItem(Result.retry()) // Here is error handling
    }

    private fun syncWithServer(alarms: MutableList<Alarm>): Single<Result> {
        val syncRequestModel = SyncRequestModel(alarms)

        return if(alarms.size != 0)
            httpManager.service().create(SyncService::class.java).sync(syncRequestModel)
                    .flatMap { result ->
                        if(result == "OK") { // TODO - the service has not been created yet
                            Timber.e("Worker - success")
                            Single.just(Result.success())
                        } else {
                            Timber.e("Worker - failure")
                            Single.just(Result.retry())
                        }
                    }
        else {
            Timber.e("Worker - no sync is necessary")
            Single.just(Result.success())
        }
    }
}
```